# ODP.NET Oracle Connection string LOAD_BALANCE=on not working

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-7.0, odp.net, oracle.manageddataaccess

I received Oracle Connection string from server team having multiple addresses with Load balance enabled.

Data Source=
(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS_LIST= (LOAD_BALANCE=on)
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.1)(PORT=MyPort))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.2)(PORT=MyPort))
)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleSID)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

We observed that all our traffic routed to first address i.e. 192.168.0.1. Same datasource successfully distribute load on weblogic and WebSphere. It seems .Net is unable to distribute load.

For reference I am using .NET 7 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core version 3.21.50.

Can you please share reason of not supporting load balancing, and what is work around to distribute load on multiple nodes.